# Android How to like Facebook Account using Android App?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

iam develop one app and up load to Play store, and create facebook account for that specific app.

`Question:` Is there any way to like a Facebook page using the Android Facebook SDK,? In one of the activity am create button when i click that button how to like My App Facebook account?

`Edit:`First is it possible in case possible how solve this issue? Any one have idea give me some suggessions?

Comment: could you please explain? I do not understand what you want to archive

Comment: I think this is exactly same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593595/how-to-like-a-facebook-page-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/.The Facebook documentation for Pages has been updated and is current . You cannot like a Page via the Graph API, even though you can read the like count information. There are not an API for it, you can try this. like android application page in facebook from application itself